# How to get current date and time from open weather api?

Tags: reactjs

How can I get the current time and date of specific location from open weather api. I am getting the timezone as a five digit no.

I have tried using new date method but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use an external API to get the current date and time?